# VSIXInstaller break my VS2017 after install extension and update some scheme from other extensions

Tags: break

I have build some extension and installed. Now my VS is break. When I try to open from menu "**extensions and update**" I get error from Visual Studio IDE: ""The local name for elements or attributes cannot be null or an empty string""

Before that I make some changes like:
 - Update the Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools NuGet package...
 - Make changes to the VSIX extension manifest..
 - installing some github extension for auto update format for manifest to support lattes format **VSIX v3** too.
 - Install this extension too
https://github.com/axodox/VsixUpdater/tree/master/VsixUpdater

$ I try to uninstall extensions but still error remain

d:
cd D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE
VSIXInstaller /q /a /u:{NTierEntityFramework.VS2017}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85u5M.png)

Please vote for me becouse I am bad reputation and can not use this forum to help other people. Thanks!!!